# Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this on my state:

```
  show: false,
```

An onclick function toggles it (using setState on the functions) but I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `show`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: show="false" or show={value.toString()}.
```

My open and closing function:

```
open() {
  this.setState({ show: true });
}

close() {
  this.setState({ show: false });
}
```

Where I'm calling the functions:

```
 <Modal show={show} onHide={this.close} overflow={overflow} className='modal'>
```

Comment: The problem is in the code that's doing `<SomeComponent show={show}` (or `show={true}` or `show={false}`). Please show us that code. Although it's interesting, because it uses the word "attribute" which suggests a DOM attribute. As far as I know, there is no DOM attribute called `show`.

Comment: `show={value.toString()}`

Comment: @Leonardo - That's incorrect for a boolean attribute. A boolean attribute is always "true" if it's present, and false if it's not present. `show="false"` is a **true** boolean attribute. (It would also be incorrect for a boolean React property. Those really do use `true` and `false`.)

Comment: @syc provide some more details

Comment: @T.J.Crowder updated the tag where I'm calling the functions

Comment: What library is `Modal` from? What does it say about the props `Modal` accepts?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder UI component from react suite https://v3.rsuitejs.com/en/components/modal

Comment: What does the `*` next to `show` in the Modal props mean?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder not sure about that

Comment: <Modal show={this.state.show} - Is this the issue?

Comment: The error message is really strange if it's really coming from `Modal`, since `Modal`'s documentation says `show` is a `boolean` property. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: `show` is state right pass it as `<Modal show={this.state.show}/>`